# VSCode intellisense for javascript not working for Canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there a problem with VScode intellisense to work on HTML 5 'canvas' element. Intellisense doesn't provide auto completion support

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.getC... /*there is no .getContext("2d")*/
```

[image]

Comment: Intellisense doesn't work well for JavaScript because of its prototype-based inheritance.

Comment: All it can know is that `getElementById()` will return a reference to an element node. It cannot predict that the element found will be a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: @Pointy
That's no excuse, if a human being can do it, software can do too.

Comment: @BEIC well if you have some ideas on how such a facility could be implemented, allowing a code editor to know what type of element a call to `.getElementById()` will return, you can create a competing tool to VSCode.

Answer (score 9):

Use JSDoc `@type` with getting `canvas` element:

```js
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

See more: [Get IntelliSense in VS Code for HTML Canvas](https://inspirnathan.com/posts/6-get-intellisense-for-html-canvas/) by Nathan Vaughn

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. Remove the canvas from HTML, and add it dynamically using javascript code.

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```